# Are Neo4j-GraphQL, GRANDstack app, schemas fixed?

Tags: neo4j, graphql

Is the schema of a GRANDstack app using the Neo4j-GraphQL integration fixed at deployment or can a structure my app such that users could modify the schema and still have the autogenerated resolvers?

Answer (score 0):

The database model is driven by the GraphQL schema, so if you change the GraphQL schema, the inferred database datamodel will be adjusted accordingly. How would you expose the functionality for users to modify the schema? What use case do you have in mind for that?

Comment: There may be organizations where it's useful if domain experts configure their own types through the web without having to upload a schema.graphql and restart the server. But even if it was possible to change the schema 'on the fly', the question remains how to build a generic UI to display these new types. It may be against the 'spirit' of GraphQL to try to achieve this.